# Load JSON data to csv Spotify related artist

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am newbee to JSON and python programming and I am looking for some help in converting below json data from Spotify related artist information to be able to load into excel or csv file.
Expected output columns:

[expected output columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYI0F.png)

[JSON related artist information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzNMH.png)

Comment: Hi, please paste the code/file format in the question instead of using a picture :) Also put the code that you have tried doing

Answer (score 1):

you can use [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) in this case. here's an example

```
import pandas
pandas.read_json("spotify.json").to_excel("spotify.xlsx")
```

basically you need to install pandas first with this command

> pip install pandas

then you can use it right away as i suggested. remember to put up the file in the same directory if you dont want to use path and change your current working directory like this

```
import os
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
os.chdir(path)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I have tried your suggested approach earlier and below is what I have got. Not all artists information is getting loaded.

href items limit next offset previous total
0 https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=Devi+S... [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.s... 20 None 0 None 1